# Download a VS 2010 extension for offline use

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsix

How can I download a VS 2010 extension (VSIX) for offline use in an internet-disconnected environment?

Comment: How do you download _anything_ in an Internet disconnected environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Download](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/) the extension directly on a computer that is Internet connected.

Transfer the install to a USB key or burn to CD.

Use the USB key or CD in the computer that is not Internet connected to install the extension.

Comment: I've added a link to VSGallery website, as he might only know how to download them from inside VS.